How can I force Word online to manually save my open document?
I have been told that Word will autosave edited content periodically however I am running into a problem where it takes too long making it unreliable.
I use Word Online to edit documents that I then publish to a CMS using a browser extension.
I am finding that Word is not autosaving the document and when I trigger the extension, the version it processes does not always include the most recent edits.
I am now going through a process of trial and error, periodically triggering the extension in 10-20 second increments to see if the content it processes includes the most recent edits.
This guessing game is disruptive and it isn't practical to go through this kind of process every time I make an edit, even for a small one.
Is there any way I can manually save the file, perhaps through a setting or some secret keystroke?

Stephanie, can you please confirm that you are in fact using Word on the Web and not using Word Desktop but autosaving to the cloud? Then triggering the browser extension to process the cloud document. It seems peculiar what you are describing.  You should include more info about the extension (and which browser you're using) as it seems to be a key piece of the puzzle.  You should also edit the question to share how you determine that the document isn't saved independent from the behavior exhibited by your browser extension.

Microsoft Word on the Web does not allow you to specify when and how often your document as noted by you and by Rubén.
My own experience has been that Online edits are autosaved almost instantaneously. If that is not the case for you, there may be something else going on on your end.
You might wish to run some tests with your extensions disabled in Microsoft Edge to see if they are part of the issue.
Be that as it may, there's no reason you should be operating in the dark as to whether your document has yet been saved because Microsoft Word on the web displays the document's current save status; there's no need to guess.
With the document open, you can tell if it's up-to-date based on the cloud icon displayed to the right of the doc name above the ribbon.
Cloud Icon Autosave Status

Not Up-To-Date
A cloud without a checkmark indicates the document is not yet up-to-date.
  
Saving Underway
The refreshing-style icon indicates the document is in the process of being saved.
  
Up-To-Date
A cloud with a green checkmark indicates the document is up-to-date.
 
Last Saved
Hovering over the cloud icon to show when it was last saved
  


No, there isn't.
Proof? The following has already been mentioned in the question.

The menus and the ribbon don't have a Save command.
The Keyboard Shortcut dialog doesn't have Save keyboard shortcut.
From the Word Online Help ( link not included):

Save a document
In Word for the web, files are automatically saved in OneDrive and are autosaved at regular intervals.
Tip: To give a new file a name, select the drop-down arrow in the title bar at the top of the page and type a name.
For more info about OneDrive and opening files from any of your devices, see Save documents online.



Things to do

First, update your device's OS and web browser. Try using your web browser in Private / Incognito mode with all the web browser extensions disabled. If the extension you are referring to is a web browser extension, allow it to run in Private / Incognito mode for testing purposes.
Try using a different device, whenever be possible using a different operative system.
Report this issue to Microsoft and the extension developers.

Things to try (do this on a dummy document)

Change the document name
Close the web browser tab. If changes aren't saved yet, the common behavior is that the web browser will alert you that the changes have not been saved yet. If you see this alert, then the autosave feature is not working and should be reported to Microsoft once you have confirmed that your computer and web browser are up to date.

